# Code runs in shell but gives 'Can't find variable' error when run from a file

Tags: javascript, python, webkit, svg, gtk

I'm using [this guy's code](https://bitbucket.org/cuu508/hxm-t) to create a dial that displays a value fed to it.

When I copy each line to the Python shell, it runs beautifully. So I thought it's time to add more functionality to it. But the VERY SAME code that works in the shell doesn't work when run from a file. It gives a "Can't find variable"  error for the variable 'showHr'

The code is:

```
import os

import gobject
import gtk
import pygtk
import sys
import webkit
pygtk.require('2.0')

URL = "/home/antimony/Oscillator Code/dials2-js.svg"
gobject.threads_init()
window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.set_resizable(True)
window.connect("destroy", lambda window, event: gtk.main_quit())
web_view = webkit.WebView()
web_view.open(URL)

vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 0)
vbox.add(web_view)
window.add(vbox)
window.show_all()
hr1  = 23000/(1*500)
web_view.execute_script("showHr(%d)" % hr1)
gtk.main()
```

What it's essentially doing is feeding the value of hr1 to showHr which is a function in the SVG file.

The function is:

```
function showHr(newBpm) {
    bpmTarget = newBpm;
}
```

I have zero clue about SVG, so I've no idea where anything's going wrong, and whether it's the fault of the SVG file or what. Why on earth can it not find 'showHr' when it could find that when run in the shell? :S

**UPDATE 1**
- I have the same problem with another program. this time with PyQt4. The problem is probably independent of the code, then. Is something wrong with my Python shell? If so, can anyone tell me how to fix it? -- Okay, this got fixed. I probably did something really stupid, like run a different file or something, cuz it worked when I tried it after a while. I have no idea what I was doing wrong.

**However the earlier problem persists and I need help!**

**UPDATE 2**
- It seems that that the line of code with the error is:

```
web_view.execute_script("showHr(%d)" % hr1)
```

I understand that to call a function in Javascript, you'd write it as "showHr(150);" (and indeed this call works when called within the SVG file). Even after modifying the code to now read

```
web_view.execute_script("showHr(%d);" % hr1)
```

it doesn't work. It still gives the same error:

```
Message: console message: undefined @0: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: showHr
```

Anyway to point it to that SVG file?

Comment: I'm not sure that this matters, but which Python shell are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.2+ (not sure what the + means, that's how it was written)

Comment: Try adding `gtk.main()` at the end of your code, as there is no main loop the window will not be displayed. To the question why it works on the python console, I can venture only a guess as my experience with pygtk/python is fairly limited. Maybe the code where you show the window is being interpreted and executed immediately without event loop and thus being displayed. And to PyQt4, it is difficult to say

Comment: It does display a window, but the dial display shows only the default value, not the value of "23000/(1*500)" that I expect it to display. And the error, or rather the message of "Can't find variable" still persists, even after adding gtk.main() at the end of my code.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell you why, but I ran into a similar issue myself. After tinkering a bit, I found:

```
web_view.execute_script("'showHr(%d)'" % hr1)
```

Comment: I tried that. Now the error's gone, but my program still doesn't seem to be acting on the value of `hr1` that I'm passing it :(